# leaderboard for javafx game

Tags: java, javafx-8

Hello stackoverflow community! I am learning to program and am working on a "duck hunt" style javafx game for mobile devices where 3 types of ducks move horizontally across the screen. Each time a certain type of duck is clicked, that type of duck gets a point next to its name.

What I would like to do is display a global leaderboard after the game so you can see which type of duck was clicked the most out of everyone who has played the game. What is everyones preferred way of implementing something like this? If you have any questions please feel free to ask me. Thanks, -H.J.

Edit (4/20/16 1:40PM PST): Because my original post was put on hold because it was deemed to vague, I wrote up a very basic example program to help explain what I am trying to do. On my menu scene I would like to retrieve the total number of clicks on the red and green rectangles for everyone who has played this game worldwide, which is currently `globalScoreRed` and `globalScoreGreen` and set to 0 because this is one of the parts I need help with.

On the playGame scene, when you hit the GG button, I would like `scoreRed` and `scoreGreen` to be submitted to the leaderboard which would adjust the values when viewed from the menu screen.

This is a very bad game and I can attest is not a game I would enjoy playing, but I am trying to learn the concepts of how to send the values and retrieve them. Once again thanks for viewing my post and helping out, you are very much appreciated.

```
package LeaderboardHelp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LeaderboardHelpMain extends Application {

Stage window;
Scene menu, playGame;

private Rectangle targetRed = new Rectangle(40, 40);
private Rectangle targetGreen = new Rectangle(40, 40);

private int scoreRed = 0;
private int scoreGreen = 0;

private Text redScoreText = new Text("Red: " + scoreRed);
private Text greenScoreText = new Text("Green: " + scoreGreen);

private int globalScoreRed = 0;
private int globalScoreGreen = 0;

private Text globalRedScoreText = new Text("Worldwide Red Clicks: " + globalScoreRed);
private Text globalGreenScoreText = new Text("Worldwide Green Clicks: " + globalScoreGreen);

private boolean playable = false;


public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window =  primaryStage;

    Button startButton = new Button("Start!");
    startButton.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(playGame));

    //menu scene layout
    VBox menuLayout = new VBox(20);
    menuLayout.getChildren().addAll(globalGreenScoreText, globalRedScoreText, startButton);

    menu = new Scene(menuLayout, 600, 600);

    Button ggButton = new Button("GG");
    ggButton.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(menu));

    targetRed.setFill(Color.RED);
    targetRed.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        scoreRed += 1;
        redScoreText.setText("Red: " + scoreRed);
    });

    targetGreen.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    targetGreen.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        scoreGreen += 1;
        greenScoreText.setText("Green: " + scoreGreen);
    });

    targetRed.setTranslateX(50);
    targetRed.setTranslateY(50);

    targetGreen.setTranslateX(100);
    targetGreen.setTranslateY(50);

    greenScoreText.setTranslateX(500);
    greenScoreText.setTranslateY(50);

    redScoreText.setTranslateX(500);
    redScoreText.setTranslateY(70);

    ggButton.setTranslateX(250);
    ggButton.setTranslateY(250);
    //game layout
    Pane gameLayout = new Pane();
    gameLayout.getChildren().addAll(targetRed, targetGreen, redScoreText, greenScoreText, ggButton);
    playGame = new Scene(gameLayout, 600, 600);

    window.setScene(menu);
    window.setTitle("Leaderboard Helper");
    window.show();



    }
}
```

Edit (4/20/16 8:45PM PST) So after more reading I came across oracles EchoServer example which is getting me on a track (not sure if its right or wrong track). I was thinking about having the server save the submitted scores in a text file.  When the `menu` scene is called by client it will connect to the server and request the scores. The server will read the text file and send scores to the application client. When the `GG` button is pressed, the score is sent to the server which reads the text file, adds the news score to old score and then overwrites the score text file. Is there a better way of doing this? I do want this to be scalable allowing lots of users to add their score at the same time.

Comment: Hi gamedev might be more appropriate for this question

Comment: Hi BevynQ, I edited my post and added a code example can you take my post off hold? Thanks!

Comment: "I was thinking about having the server save the submitted scores in a text file.."  Nope.  Save the scores to a relational database.  Write  REST functions ton the server o save a score, retrieve the top scores,  and retrieve the top scores of a particular user.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Gilbert Le Blanc, I am still fairly new with java and havnt heard of REST functions until you mentioned it. I will be looking into it in detail in the morning as it is getting late here. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A web service would be required.  A simple one that takes maybe the type of duck and the number of times it was clicked.

   POST /duck/{type}/{clicks}
2. The web-service would need to be secured using HTTPS or HMAC, or better yet both.
3. For HMAC the key would need to be hidden and obfuscated in your code.  Security is always breakable, its about making the effort not worth it for such a small payout to any would-be hacker.
4. To do HMAC properly one should use a NONCE when creating the digest (aka signature).  The NONCE should have a short expiration time.  Many implementations use the timestamp as a NONCE, other implementations have the NONCE being provided by the web service.  For simplicity I would go with the former.  If the NONCE is older than 2 or 3 seconds, then reject the request.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jose Martinez, I added a code example to hopefully clarify what I would like to achieve.